# C# Where to store variable properties setter's

Tags: c#, class, struct, properties, controls

I have a control variable named `a` more specifically a Label. I want to be able to set the `a` properties while using some other public variables, I have it done like this with a simple struct :

```
    public Label Username = new Label();
    public struct UsernameProperties
    {
        public Color BackColor;
        public Color ForeColor;
        public int FontSize;
    }
```

So later we can do :

```
Username.ForeColor = UsernameProperties.ForeColor;
```

while we are able to set the `UsernameProperties.ForeColor;` from the other classes. So is the struct the best place to store those variables ? Or there is some already built struct that will do the job.

After this I inherit the class which contains the Label variable :

```
    public class UsersProperties
    {
//some other variables
        public Label Username = new Label();
        public struct UsernameProperties
        {
            public string Name;
            public Color BackColor;
            public Color ForeColor;
            public int FontSize;
        }
    }

    public class Player : UsersProperties
    {
        public Player(Label Username)
        {
            Username.Text = UsernameProperties.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could create a Username class that extends the Label class. That way you can just create an instance of username. Wont that work better?

Comment: Can you check my updated question are you sure it will work :P

Comment: You could try running it yourself and just see if it will work...

Answer (score -1):

```
var person = {
    firstName: "Celcom",
    lastName : "Africa",

    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};

// Display data from the object using a getter: 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName;
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question